# What is the nth term of this sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the Taylor Sum for this function: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}$

I got to this sum using power sum properties but I can't find the nth term: $$1(\frac{x}{2})^0 + 3(\frac{x}{2})^1+6(\frac{x}{2})^2+10(\frac{x}{2})^3+15(\frac{x}{2})^4+...$$

I know it's something related to the triangular number but I can't find the nth term of the sum.

Comment: Please use Latex and at least clarify the function.

Comment: $1=\frac{1\cdot 2}{2}, 3=\frac{2\cdot 3}{2}, 6=\frac{3\cdot 4}{2}, 10=\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}, 15=\frac{5\cdot 6}{2}$.
So the coefficient of the $n$th term is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and the power of $x/2$ is $n-1$.

Comment: The series starts at 0, so for n = 0 it should be 1.

Comment: ok, easy fix...

Comment: How would that be? Sorry, I'm not very good at this...

Comment: So, you're not Gauss.  That's OK, most of us aren't. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$g(x)=\frac {1}{1-x/2}=1+(x/2)+(x/2)^2+(x/2)^3+...=$$

$$g(x)=\sum _0^\infty (x/2)^n$$
Note that your function $$f(x)=\frac {1}{(1-x/2)^3} $$ is simply $$f(x) =2g''(x)$$
$$g'(x)=\sum _1^\infty (n/2)(x/2)^{n-1}$$
$$g''(x)=\sum _2^\infty (n(n-1)/4)(x/2)^{n-2}$$
$$f(x) =2g''(x)=\sum _2^\infty (n(n-1)/2)(x/2)^{n-2}=$$

$$\sum _0^\infty \frac {(n+1)(n+2)}{2}(x/2)^{n}=$$

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the
generalized binomial theorem:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)

$(x+y)^r
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k}x^{r-k}y^k
$
where
$\binom{r}{k}
=\dfrac{r(r-1)...(r-k+1)}{k!}
=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(r-j)}{k!}
$.

The most common special case
is $x=1$ so

$(1+y)^r
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k}y^k
$.

With some fiddling
with the binomial coefficient,
you can get the form
which directly applies
to your problem:

$\dfrac1{(1-x)^s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{s+k-1}{k}x^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
$.

When $s=3$ this gives

$\dfrac1{(1-x)^3}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+2}{2}x^k
$.

Comment: With $s=3$ we get $\binom{k+2}{k}=\binom{k+2}{2}$ which is where the triangular numbers come from.

Comment: Yes. I'll modify my answer to reflect this.